# Include tests in binary R package

Tags: r, unit-testing, package, testthat

I am using `testthat` to write unit tests for my R packages. I have seen a few package authors (like those from `Rcpp` and `ggplot2`) distributing their unit tests with the binary files.
However, when I build my packages with RStudio (0.98.1102) and `devtools` (1.7.0) the `tests` folder is not included in the zip file. Do I have to add the folder manually or is it possible to get this done automatically by setting some option?

BTW: I am on a Win7 machine using R v3.1.2 and RTools v3.1.0.1942.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Got it.
Found the information on the github page of `testthat` (it's at the very bottom).
https://github.com/hadley/testthat

> The advantage of this new structure is that the user has control over whether or not tests are installed using the --install-tests parameter to R CMD install, or INSTALL_opts = "--install-tests" argument to install.packages(). I'm not sure why you wouldn't want to install the tests, but now you have the option.

The command to build the binary package WITH the tests is

```
devtools::build(binary=TRUE, args=c("--preclean", "--install-tests"))
```

Comment: Do you know a way to do this directly from GitHub e.g. with `devtools::install_github`? I don't think `devtools::build` will accept a URL path.

Comment: The referenced section has been removed in [Sept 2015](https://github.com/r-lib/testthat/commit/0a7d2).

Answer (score 1):

On Windows, you need code like

```r
install.packages("dwdradar", INSTALL_opts = "--install-tests", type="source")
```

Without the `type` option, the test folder is not installed.