# How to test an installed package with testthat?

Tags: r, testthat

I would like to test an installed package, but this returns an error.

```
library(testthat)
test_package("testthat")
# Error: No tests found for testthat
```

test_package ([source here](https://github.com/hadley/testthat/blob/c201c3628a2727d7dd9e9cf5c35ac68caa14457e/R/test-package.r)) returns this error because `system.file("tests", package = package)` is empty. In fact, the `tests` directory is missing from the package installed.

```
list.dirs(system.file("", package = "testthat"))
# [1] "/home/paul/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2/testthat/"     
# [2] "/home/paul/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2/testthat//help"
# [3] "/home/paul/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2/testthat//html"
# [4] "/home/paul/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2/testthat//libs"
# [5] "/home/paul/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2/testthat//Meta"
# [6] "/home/paul/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2/testthat//R"
```

How to install a package so that its tests directory remains present?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31380593/include-tests-in-binary-r-package suggests a way to bundle tests into package WITHOUT placing in inst

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the author chooses not to put the tests in the `inst/` directory, then they will not be installed with the package and you cannot run the tests via the installed package.

So there's nothing you can do, short of modifying the source package and re-installing. But at that point, you might as well just run the tests on the source package.

Comment: I see `inst/tests` is mentioned in [this other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19287167/2641825). So it looks  like if I want to disseminate tests with my source package, I have to place them in the inst/ directory. Why Hadley didn't mention this in [his package testing chapter](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/tests.html)?

Comment: @PaulRougieux: I don't know why he didn't mention it; you could ask him.

Comment: My original intend was to share tests with my source package. I simply moved `tests` to `inst/tests`, rebuilt the package and now `testthat::test_package()` works.

Comment: the answer by @stats0007 mentions an important option that is missing in this accepted answer: `install.packages("testthat", INSTALL_opts = "--install-tests")`

Answer (score 5):

You can test packages with

```
tools::testInstalledPackage("package")
```

But I think it just works only if the tests are in inst/

There is also

```
install.packages("testthat", INSTALL_opts = "--install-tests")
```

to install also the tests with the package. But also just works if test are in inst/

So probably best you download the source package and run:

```
devtools::test()
```